# Set up VNC to use iPad Pro with Apple Pencil as a graphics tablet

Tags: ipad, remote-desktop

I work with photoshop in my Macbook Air. I want to use my iPad Pro with Apple Pencil as an input device (because Photoshop for the iPad is still too limited for some tasks). I don't want to use Duet Display or Astropad (already tried and they don't suit me).

I managed to mirror the computer screen into the tablet using VNC client, but the tablet behaves as a trackpad:

- tap and drag = move the cursor
- double tap = click

How can I make the motion of the Apple Pencil around the screen to be exactly reproduced on my computer screen? I mean, when I tap a particular point in the tablet, have it reproduced in the screen in the same screen position?

Answer (score 2):

I’m slightly expecting you’ll find this workable since AstroPad and Luna display are the best solution I know for your specific use case, but I’ll presume you have reasons to discard them as solutions.

- https://lunadisplay.com/
- https://astropad.com/

(Everyone else, use the tools above if you can, the tools below are the best screen share and tablet apps as well, so I highly recommend all these links)

The tool I use for Mac Remote Desktop is screens app and you can use your phone or a second iPad as a touch device or use the pencil in touch mode as you request.

- https://apps.apple.com/us/app/screens/id655890150

Been using screens for years, and only my full time artist colleagues use the accelerated versions, but they love the custom tools when they cant just render on iPad directly which is the case more and more. Screens is way better than the other “vnc” apps due to this feature and a few others IMO.

Also, check out touchpad if you don’t need to see the content VNC on the iPad, that is even more responsive than the above solutions.

- https://apps.apple.com/us/app/touchpad/id297623931